# R Studio: saving and loading custom defined variables

Tags: r, variables, store, workspace

I want to save all the parameter values (more than 100) used for a certain analysis for the purpose of

1. reference: to make a little report that can be read by anyone (non-programmers)
2. loading all these variables the next time to run the same analysis (so the can easily be loaded into the workspace)

I was thinking of

1. a simple text file/pdf/word document
2. some kind dynamic structure like in matlab: a big variable that holds all other parameter values (or a workspace file, in matlab that would be .mat and I would only want to save a small part of the current workspace)

Which variable type can I best use for this and which are the best tools for exporting text info in a nicely formatted way (for purpose 1).

Thx!

Comment: For *"loading all these variables the next time"*, I suggest the `.rda` (Rdata) format using `save` (or `saveRDS`). If your *"reference"* is when outside of R, then I'd use JSON format (using the `jsonlite` package). Other "text file" options risk being lossy; PDF and word formats are an easy and adamant "no".

Comment: Thx, will look into that!

Comment: If your *"reference"* it outside of R and a visual reference (i.e.,  just looking at the file, not parsing it), then I suggest `jsonlite::toJSON(..., pretty=TRUE)`, as it tends to be more human-readable (at the expense of extra blank space).

Comment: Consider using two methods: a visual reference for other non-programmers using [RMarkdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) with some elbow-grease on your part, ***and*** save as `.rda` or `.json` for immediate, unambiguous, and direct re-parsing for later use. I've seen reports that had raw json data on the last page (for simple consumption, choosing to distribute a single document), but I find that a little sloppy and and absolutely dependent on the size of the data.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about Rmarkdown, thx!